# How to get hidden field value from invisible iframe using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

Ok it's 01:16AM here and i can't solve this simple problem.
 I use the invisible iframe to upload photo and send some text into DB. The iframe point to upload.php and return me hidden textfield with insert_id (the id of the last row in DB) - i need this information for other function.

Here is how my iframe:

```
 <iframe name="image_upload_frame" id="image_upload_frame" height="1" width="1" style="visibility: hidden">
```

It is empty at the beginning, but after image upload, it has this html:

```
 echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
     echo '<input type="hidden" id="session_id" value="'.$wpdb->insert_id.'" />';
```

Here is my javascript to get session)id value:

```
var row_id = $("#image_upload_frame").contents().find("#session_id");
  alert(row_id.val());
```

It doesn't work. Debugger says nothing - it just stop, no error, no notification.

Anyone can help? I'd like to hear for other options how to pass data from iframe to the main window.

Thanks,

Comment: When does your javascript fire? Immediately after you create the hidden iframe or on the page load event of that iframe? If it fires before the iframe is ready, `$("#image_upload_frame").contents().find("#session_id")` will get no results.

Comment: *"Ok it's 01:16AM here and i can't solve this simple problem."* - Get some sleep, you'll probably wake up tomorrow morning with a solution, right after your first cup of coffee and breakfast; it works having a fresh start ;-)

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you "seem" to be using sessions. I may have a solution for you, but I'll need to see more code. And if you're not using sessions, then that can be a solution and it works with JS also; to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not assuming wrong, your html is like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" style="display: none"></iframe>
    <form method="post" target="hidden_iframe" action="./test1.php" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_upload" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

my idea is in your server side , you write a javascript code to call your client side's javascript(actural is iframe call main window).so your client code should like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" style="display: none"></iframe>
    <form method="post" target="hidden_iframe" action="./test1.php" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_upload" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
    function callFromServerSide(params){
        alert(params);
    }        
    </script>
</body>
```

and you server side should like this(in my case is test1.php):

```
<?php
$last_insert_id=100;
echo "
<script>
window.top.callFromServerSide('".$last_insert_id."');                    
</script>";
?>
```

have fun..